# Error while convertiong enhanced for loop with java to c#

Tags: java, c#, for-loop

I try to have this enhanced for loop of a Java code in my C# code:

```
for (float value : array) {
    if (Float.isInfinite(value) || Float.isNaN(value)) {
        value = 0;
    }
}
```

I tried this out:

```
foreach (float value in array)
{
    if (float.IsInfinity(value) || float.IsNaN(value))
    {
        value = 0;
    }
}
```

But I have this error that told me I have not the right to modify value because it is an iteration variable.

Comment: It's bad that the first one compiles. It's a hidden bug. Java just lets you write it. At least C# tells you about it. Not being able to modify a loop variable is a good rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a normal for loop if you want to update the iterator variable:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.Length; i++)
{

    if (float.IsInfinity(array[i]) || float.IsNaN(array[i]))
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

From C# specifications:

> The iteration variable corresponds to a read-only local variable with
>   a scope that extends over the embedded statement. During execution of
>   a foreach statement, the iteration variable represents the collection
>   element for which an iteration is currently being performed. A
>   compile-time error occurs if the embedded statement attempts to modify
>   the iteration variable (via assignment or the ++ and -- operators) or
>   pass the iteration variable as a ref or out parameter.

Comment: @dou BTW: In Java the content of the array wouldn't be changed either.